# Open and closed complex sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, complex-numbers

was wondering if someone could shine some light on the highlighted half of this question? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please excuse me for the poor format of the question, I'm new to this! Thanks in advance.

> Determine whether the following set is closed: 
>   $$D = \{z\text{ is complex}: \Re(z)\ge\frac13 \text{ or } \Re(z)\le2\}$$
>   **Is the set $D$ open**? Justify your answer.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation should get you started on MathJax typesetting.

Comment: Isn't that set all of $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @Mike I hadn't seen that!

Comment: @Mike: It looks like all of$\mathbb C$ to me.

Comment: I would think the "or" should be "and" here.

Comment: @SuzuHirose I would wait for the OP's reactions. Maybe it is just a typo, maybe it was a trick question. We never know.

Comment: Or one of the real parts was meant to be imaginary?

Comment: I think maybe the point is that it is indeed open, but not "obviously" so.

Comment: @SuzuHirose: Either that orone of the $\Re$ should be a $\Im$. - Not that it would change the answer.

Comment: There is no point in thinking about what the question _might have been_. It may as well be intentional

Comment: @AlexR It's plausible that there's a pedagogical intention here. It's that it's possible to define a set in a way that doesn't make the fact that it's open immediately apparent, yet it can still be open.

Comment: I've already shown that the set is indeed closed by proving its compliment is open. However I was trying to work out how to show the set is or isn't open?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
$D=\mathbb C$, so the question is:
*Is $\mathbb C$ open?*